# How to avoid DeploymentItem? I need to deploy a file at once for all tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, deployment, mstest

I want to deploy a file from a single place in code, I don't want to decorate many tests by the same attribute with the same parameter.

I use mstest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can decorate the test class with *[DeploymentItem]* attribute so you do not need to do it for each single tests.

Alternative you could use **Deployment** page of *.testsettings* file, see [How to: Deploy Files for Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)